# Create new column based on values in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm playing with FIFA 19 data set which has 'Work Rate' column that stores attacking & defending work rates for the players e.g. ('Medium/ Medium). I'd like to create two additional columns (right next to original one) that could store these features separately; let's call them 'Work Rate Attacking', 'Work Rate Defending'. I can't figure out the best way to do this, I've been considering applying simple split function but it returns ValueError.

```
def split_work_rate(text, work_type):
    while not pd.isnull(text):
        new_text = text.split('/')
        if work_type == 'Attacking':
            work_rate_attacking = new_text[0]
            return work_rate_attacking
        else:
            work_rate_defending = new_text[1]
            return work_rate_defending


def create_new_work_rates(data):
    cols = ['Work Rate']
    data['Work Rate Attacking'] = data[cols].apply(split_work_rate, args=('Attacking',))
    data['Work Rate Defending'] = data[cols].apply(split_work_rate, args=('Defending',))
    return data
```

> ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index Work
>   Rate')

Comment: Do you need parse only one column? Or `cols = ['Work Rate']` should be multiple values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the problem is this line:

```
if work_type == 'Attacking':
```

What you were probably thinking when you wrote that was that `pandas` would compare the value in each row to `'Attacking'` and go down the appropriate branch.

However, in fact, `pandas` applies such comparisons to the *whole* `Series` at once. The result of the comparison to `'Attacking'`, therefore, is not a single boolean value, but another `Series`. There is no non-ambiguous way to turn a `Series` of boolean values to a single boolean value, so the `if` test does not work.

In any case, this is probably not the best way to do it. Try this:

```
data[['Work Rate Attacking', 'Work Rate Defending']] = data['Work Rate'].str.split('/', expand=True)
```

This uses the `str` accessor to split the `Series` into a `DataFrame`, which can then be assigned to the two columns you want.